# Remote Config Device Language Changes in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, firebase-remote-config

I am encountering a problem, where localization works fine, but the applications needs to be *restarted* in order for the changes to *propagate*.

#### Orientation changes

I know about [`OrientationBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/OrientationBuilder/OrientationBuilder.html), which will call its builder whenever it detects a change in the device's *orientation*, which in e.g. *Android* would be considered as a *configuration* change, just like device language changes.

#### Language changes

Is there something like ***`LanguageBuilder`***? I could not find anything on my own and not on *[flutter.io](https://flutter.io)* nor on *[pub](https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter/packages?q=languagebuilder)*. I have read [this tutorial](https://flutter.io/tutorials/internationalization/) and know about `Locale`, but I do not see a `Stream` for `Locale`.

My problem is that changing the language in *iOS* and *Android* native is really smooth. It gets handled automatically and perfectly integrates with services like [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/).

I really wonder if there is some method that will allow me to refresh my localization.

#### Question

So I am asking how I can refresh my *Remote Config* when the *device language* changes.

Comment: Hello, did you get a chance to solve this problem?

Comment: @user482594 Yes, see my [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60725209/6509751).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Device language changes* can be detected using a [`WidgetsBindingObserver`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html).

It is the simplest to use it with a `StatefulWidget` in your [`State`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) (`with WidgetsBindingObserver`):

```dart
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void didChangeLocales(List<Locale> locale) {
    // The device language was changed when this is called.
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
  ...
}
```

This means that you can now *reload* your [`RemoteConfig`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_remote_config/latest/firebase_remote_config/RemoteConfig-class.html) in [`didChangeLocales`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver/didChangeLocales.html):

```dart
@override
void didChangeLocales(List<Locale> locale) {
  _updateRemoteConfig();
}

Future<void> _updateRemoteConfig() async {
  final remoteConfig = await RemoteConfig.instance;
  await remoteConfig.activateFetched(); // This will apply the new locale.
}
```

Comment: is it detectable when I change the language outside the app means in the phone settings ?

Comment: @Fatimaayaa that's the whole idea I guess...

Answer (score 7):

No there's no `Builder` for `Locale`.

Instead, there's an `InheritedWidget` which you can subscribe to using `Localizations.of`.

Since it is an `InheritedWidget`, all widgets that call `Localizations.of` will automatically refresh on locale change.

**EDIT** :

A example on how to live reload text using Flutter Locale system :

Let's assume you have the following class that holds translations :

```
class MyData {
  String title;

  MyData({this.title});
}
```

You'd then have a `LocalizationsDelegate` that contains such data. A dumb implementation would be the following :

```
class MyLocale extends LocalizationsDelegate<MyData> {
  MyData data;

  MyLocale(this.data);

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) {
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Future<MyData> load(Locale locale) async {
    return data;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(MyLocale old) {
    return old.data != data;
  }
}
```

To use it simply pass it to `MaterialApp.localizationsDelegates` (be sure to add `flutter_localizations` to your `pubspec.yaml`) :

```
LocalizationsDelegate myLocale = MyLocale(MyData(title: "Foo"));
...


MaterialApp(
  localizationsDelegates: [
    myLocale,
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
);
```

You can then freely live reload your translations by replacing `myLocale` with a new `MyLocale` instance.

Here's a full example of a click counter app. But where the current count is instead stored inside `Locale` (because why not ?)

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

class MyCount {
  String count;

  MyCount({this.count});
}

class MyCountLocale extends LocalizationsDelegate<MyCount> {
  MyCount data;

  MyCountLocale(this.data);

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) {
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Future<MyCount> load(Locale locale) async {
    return data;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(MyCountLocale old) {
    return old.data != data;
  }
}

Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  ValueNotifier<int> count = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
  LocalizationsDelegate myLocale;

  @override
  void initState() {
    count.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        myLocale = MyCountLocale(MyCount(count: count.value.toString()));
      });
    });
    myLocale = MyCountLocale(MyCount(count: count.value.toString()));

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        myLocale,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      home: MyHomePage(count: count),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueNotifier<int> count;

  MyHomePage({this.count});

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      primary: true,
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => widget.count.value++,
            child: Icon(Icons.plus_one),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text(Localizations.of<MyCount>(context, MyCount).count),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When you call `Localization.of(context, type)`, this method will make that `context` rebuild whenever the associated locale change

Comment: If you don't know what `InheritedWidget` are, they are typically used to bind a `BuildContext` to a data and force it to reload on change. Where `InheritedWidget` is the holder of that data.

Comment: You may want to have a look into [this](https://flutter.rocks/2018/03/02/separating-build-environments-part-one/). It includes a nice example on how to use the InheritedWidget with `updateShouldNotify`.

Comment: Added an example. Go take a look :)

Comment: Here I made a dumb example where your `Locale` handle all languages at once. Although you could have multiple `myLocale` each handling a different language using `isSupported` method (and load your confs using `load` method)

Comment: Maybe make a question just your actual remote config setup. Dunno what can I add here.

Comment: Taking a look at my [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60725209/6509751), you might see why I thought that your answer was not a good answer to the question.