# Flutter localization with Firebase Remote Config

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-localizations, flutter-easy-localization

In my Flutter project I am going to use localization with Firebase Remote Config
In Firebase remote config all locales in one json file:

```
{
 "page1": {
   "text1":{
     "ru" :"russian text",
     "en" :"english text"
   }
 },
  "page2": {
    "text1":{
      "ru" :"russian text",
      "en" :"english text"
    }
  },
 "common": {
    "text1":{
      "ru" :"russian text",
      "en" :"english text"
    },
    "text2":{
      "ru" :"russian text",
      "en" :"english text"
    }
 }
}
```

Is it possible to implement localization with Getx or Easy Localization in such format?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with the Easy Localization. You create a RemoteConfigAssetLoader class that extends the AssetLoader class of the Easy Localization and then overwrite its load() method. See more details here: [Flutter localization using Firebase Remote Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74195927/flutter-localization-using-firebase-remote-config).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I created AssetLoader and overwrite load method, but now how I can access to json file?